# Getting NoClassDefFoundError by using Ghost4j

Tags: java, itext, bouncycastle, pdf-conversion, ghost4j

this is my first Questing here and i didn't found any solutions to my Problem.
Please don't take it amiss, if my text is broken English.

For my program I want to resize images inside an existing PDF-Document. This should happens automatically within a Java program.
During my search, I found the Ghost4j Library in the web, which can solve my problem - maybe!

As a first test with Ghost4j to tryout if it works, I want to load my PDF Document out of the MySQL Database and check out the pageCount.

Here ist my short code:

```
... 
for (File file : convertableFiles) {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getFile());

        PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument();
        doc.load(inputStream);
        System.out.println(doc.getPageCount());
}
...
```

The error comes at line 45 = doc.load(inputStream)

(Note: if I use new File(Path) for doc.load and set a pdfSample Document. It works. But not with inputStream)

When I execute my programm i'll get everytime this Excption:

```
Sep 29, 2014 4:54:53 PM ch.carauktion.dbresize.DBFileResizer convert
INFORMATION: P1 (asc): 0 / 1
Sep 29, 2014 4:54:54 PM ch.carauktion.dbresize.DBFileResizer run
SCHWERWIEGEND: P1 (asc): Exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument.load(PDFDocument.java:45)
    at ch.carauktion.dbresize.pdf.DBPdfResizer.convertFiles(DBPdfResizer.java:50)
    at ch.carauktion.dbresize.DBFileResizer.convert(DBFileResizer.java:114)
    at ch.carauktion.dbresize.DBFileResizer.run(DBFileResizer.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 10 more
```

For this Project implements Libraries, which all comes from the downloaded ghost4j package:

- ghost4j-0.5.1
- iText-2.1.7
- jna-3.3.0
- log4j-1.2.15
- commons-logging-1.1.1
- commons-io-1.3.1
- commons-beanutils-1.8.3

Example Sites at my search for this Error:

http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/mailman/itext-questions/thread/4F422974.1070002@redlab.be/

http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-bouncycastle-asn1-ASN1OctetString-td3427288.html

I understand that iText 2.1.7 isn't supported anymore and i should use Version 5.x.x, but it doesn't work here to download the newest iText Lib, when in the Ghost4j Jar apparently  the Lib 2.1.7 are used.
Otherwise, maybe its my fault and I didn't understand at this moment how to implements correctly the newest Version.

PS:
I'am using Java 1.7, Eclipse Kepler, Windows 8.1

I'll be glad, someone is knowing any solutions or can help me a little bit.

Wudmaan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the Bouncycastle dependency.

I don't think a PDF library would depends on that, except if there is a need to protect the PDF, but you'll find Bouncycastle here: http://bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

Try with `bcprov-jdk14-147.jar` and/or `bcprov-ext-jdk14-147.jar` downloadable from [Maven Central repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/):

- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.47/
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk14/1.47/
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/1.47/
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bctsp-jdk14/1.47/

If that still don't work, try with [the other excluded dependencies](https://github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j/blob/master/pom.xml) listed here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Note: you should use Maven to take of those dependencies.

Comment: *Try with bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar and bcprov-ext-jdk15on-151.jar* - I don't think using bc 1.51 is a good idea. IText 2.1.7 is ancient and quite likely relies on the bc API before the 1.47 rupture.

Comment: I took that (and the pom.xml dependencies) into account.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It works correctly. I thought its an internal mistake in iText :).

Comment: While it works, I would advise you to try to use maven/gradle/etc. I only answered because I know globally how to resolve `NoClassDefFoundError` or `ClassNotFoundException`, not because I know ghost4j or iText. And since Ghost4j exclude those dependencies, there might be some reason as to why (which I don't know!).